# Cannot minify CSS file

Tags: webpack, minify, webpack-4

I'm trying to use **Webpack 4** for my project. All plugins works except `extract-text-webpack-plugin`.

**Actual Behavior**: when I build the project there are no errors at all and minified file also

**Expected behavior**: get minified CSS file ( `styles.css` ) in `dist` folder

**output**

[image: terminal]

**file structure**

[image: files]

**webpack.config**

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'index': './src/index.js',
    },
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
        ],
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( 'css-loader' ),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                            emitFile: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin( {
            filename: './src/styles.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            minify: {
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                html5: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
            },
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: false,
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: true,
            },
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: Check out this [Webpack-4 Demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo). Hope it helps with configuring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need:

1. to add a stylesheet to the entry point

   > `entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/styles.css']`
2. to add options into rules for `ExtractTextPlugin`

   ```
   use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
          minimize: true,
      },
   })
   ```
3. change pathname for file in `plugins`

> `filename: './styles.css'`

**Full config**

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./src/index.js', './src/styles.css'],
    resolveLoader: {
        modules: [
            'node_modules',
        ],
    },
    mode: 'production',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'html-loader',
                        options: {
                            minimize: true,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        minimize: true,
                    },
                }),
            },
            {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif)$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
                            emitFile: false,
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin( {
            filename: './styles.css',
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: './src/index.html',
            filename: 'index.html',
            inject: 'body',
            hash: true,
            minify: {
                removeAttributeQuotes: true,
                collapseWhitespace: true,
                html5: true,
                removeComments: true,
                removeEmptyAttributes: true,
                minifyCSS: true,
            },
        }),
        new UglifyJsPlugin({
            cache: true,
            parallel: true,
            uglifyOptions: {
                compress: false,
                ecma: 6,
                mangle: true,
            },
            sourceMap: true,
        }),
    ],
};
```

Comment: For those coming to this answer a few months later, `css-loader` no longer has a `minimize` option and now recommends post-processing with `cssnano` or `optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: To expand on the comment above, here's a link to webpack v4 documentation explaining how to setup CSS minification: https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin#minimizing-for-production